# how to query multiple edges with OR relationship by Gremlin

Tags: java, gremlin, graph-databases

I have a topology,

Interface<----Node---->Ip,

And the condition is OR between these 2 edges.
Node---->IP or Node---->Interface

How to use Gremlin  query it in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what your OR condition is, but if it's to say, "traverses from Node vertices to either IP or Interface vertices", then:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Node").out().hasLabel("IP","Interface")
```

If you are referring to OR conditions based on edge labels, then the approach is similar:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Node").out("IP", "Interface")
```

Comment: Thanks  Stephan, but how about Node--(link type 1)-->IP or Node--(link type 2)-->Interface ?